# What does exit: do

Tags: c++

I'm reading some C++ code for openThread, I've never programmed C++ but I wanted to know what the `exit:` does near the bottom followed by `return error;`

What's the difference with having a `exit:` and not having one

```
ThreadError otGetParentInfo(otInstance *aInstance, otRouterInfo *aParentInfo)
{
    ThreadError error = kThreadError_None;
    Router *parent;

    VerifyOrExit(aParentInfo != NULL, error = kThreadError_InvalidArgs);

    parent = aInstance->mThreadNetif.GetMle().GetParent();
    memcpy(aParentInfo->mExtAddress.m8, parent->mMacAddr.m8, OT_EXT_ADDRESS_SIZE);
    aParentInfo->mRloc16 = parent->mValid.mRloc16;

exit:
    return error;
}
```

Comment: it's label doc here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto

Comment: That looks like a goto label. Using goto is highly discouraged under any circumstances in C++. Also I'm really not sure why are you reading about some thread errors when you never programmed in C++.

Comment: @MarošBeťko Can we not go into this... There are legitimately good uses of goto, like breaking out of nested loops or cleaning up resources (when you don't feel like RAII-wrapping every little type an API exposes).

Comment: Well if you don't feel like RAII wrapping everything why are you writing in C++ when the RAII is one of the best features C++ provides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a mark for the GOTO statement.

It allows the program to jump to this mark from (almost) any point in the code. This is usually used in hardware-programming or embedded programming when you cannot return from deeply nested structures without using lots of `break` statements or similiar situations for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
exit:
```

It's label that is used together with `goto`. This `goto` `lable` is usually used to jump out of a block of code when some error condition happens.

Comment: @MarošBeťko I think He just describe what the label "exit" in this code is intent to. He don't say that it's a good practice in c++.

Comment: @MarošBeťko the piece of code is for a embedded/hardware programming bash.d mentioned this is a useful statement in hardware programming.

I assume this can be a good practice for hardware programming

Comment: @Albert: he said "usually used", whether it is useful probably depends on the situation (even in embedded software) but if you're not sure, avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct, but are not making it clear that the label can be any word that is not a reserved keyword. `exit` is just one such name.

And another thing, in your example where there is no corresponding `goto exit;` normal program execution simply bypasses the label, it has no bearing on the functionality.

Comment: That fixed a lot of confusion. Thanks!